# Multiple expressions in one command using the -e option (sed)

Tags: sed

- Use the `–e` option to include 2 replace commands for an example file:

  - 1 to replace all “erors” with “errors” and
  - 1 to replace all last words with “final.”

What command will do this?

Comment: Could you add input and expected output?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Well, like you write, `sed` will do this. Have you looked at `man sed`? Have you tried anything yet? This is not a free code writing service. You're expected to try something before asking here. Please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
sed 's/erors/errors/g;s/last/final/g'
```

As well as:

```
sed -e 's/erors/errors/g' -e 's/last/final/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

In `awk` you can do

```
cat file
these are all erors that I have

awk '{sub(/erors/,"errors");$NF="final"}1' file
these are all errors that I final
```